# jQuery to update HTML in a Variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have a chunk of HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<div id="MySeparateHTMLCode" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; ">This is some text
    <div id="DIV2">My Text That Changes</div>
    <div id="DIV3">This is more text</div>
</div>
```

That chunk of HTML is being read into a variable

```
var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html();
```

I now need to use jQuery to change "My Text That Changes" to "My New Variable Text" when it is inside the variable.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to accomplish this:

```
 $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').find("#DIV2").text("My New Variable Text");
```

Or:

```
$('#MySeparateHTMLCode #DIV2').text("My New Variable Text");
```

Or:

```
$("#DIV2").text("My New Variable Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text inside html:

```
var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html('My New Variable Text');
```

But I suggest you to use text() method instead of html() method.

Comment: This looks like "My New Variable Text" is being changed when myVar is being set.   In my instance, the variable is already set, and later (in a different area of code) I want to change "My New Variable Text"

Comment: Then you have to do like this: var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode');myVar.find('#DIV2').html('My New Variable Text');

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
$('#MySeparateHTMLCode #DIV2').text('My New Variable Text');
```

You could also use the variable `myVar`, but note that `.html()` returns a *string*. So you need to search through the string and find and replace `"My Text That Changes"` with `"My New Variable Text"`, then change the HTML with the new text you made from `myVar`. It would be a bit more work than necessary (in my opinion). If you wish to do that though you can do this:

```
var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html(); // Get text
myVar = myVar.replace("My Text That Changes", "My New Variable Text"); // change text
$('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html(myVar); // place in HTML
```

**[Here is an example of above](http://jsfiddle.net/c3zcr2sb/)**. But again, it's not really recommend.

Comment: @charlietfl For which part?

Comment: @charlietfl That's for if they really wants to use their variable. Note from the question they wish to use the variable defined in the question. I've pointed out you don't want to do it that way, but gave a solution if the OP really wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to simply `clone()` the main element instead of capturing it's html. You can then use jQuery methods on the clone.

Example:

```
var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').clone();

/* somewhere else in code */
myVar.find('#DIV2').text('new text');
/* do something with modified html */
$('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html(myVar.html());
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1rdbyy05/)**</kbd>

Alternatively you can create a new element who's innerHTML is the string in myVar and maniplate that new element using jQuery methods

```
var myVar = $('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html();
/* create element that contains string from mYVar*/
var $el=$('<div>').html( myVar);
/* change text */
$el.find('#DIV2').text('new text');
/* do something with new innerHTML*/
$('#MySeparateHTMLCode').html($el.html());
```